# Unity Raycast going through floor with Oculus

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting, oculus

I'm working with Unity in VR (with Oculus). I basically followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1zJw0F_3UZ0) to enable hand tracking and hand interactions with raycasts and UI. So right now I can interact with my hands with a Canvas, click on buttons by pinching my fingers (which triggers a click event), etc.

My problem is that I would need to instantiate objects on the floor by clicking aswell, and the object would spawn where the raycast points. But right now, my raycast is going through the floor, I do not manage to make the floor stop the raycast. I would need to point at the floor and when I click, get the pointed positions.

PS: my scene is pretty simple, I'm using Oculus prefabs like OVRCameraRig, UIHelpers for the laser...

Comment: Are you sure the raycast is going through the floor and not that the object being spawned center is at the raycast point making it appear to be below a little?

Comment: There's a sphere at the end of the raycast. When I point the canvas, I see the sphere because the canvas stops the raycast. When I point the floor, I don't see the sphere, so the floor is not stopping the raycast. 
And also, I don't know how to spawn a object at the pointed position right now

Comment: Some floor surfaces aren't that great for AR, I remember having issues with a rug , it could just be the surfaces you are trying to project on.

Comment: I didn't mention AR sorry if it was unclear, I mean, my "floor" is just a unity plane. All VR

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the collider and whether its on a targeted layer, and if it is maybe you are hitting a collider before the floor. Debug the object it does hit to make sure